# How to create pdf-file and save to the server?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, asp.net-web-api

I want to do is to create the pdf report using jsreport with web api. All I have got is the response from jsreport server as the pdf content in the following format:

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (þÿ) /Creator (þÿ) /Producer (þÿQt 4.8.4 \(C\) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary\(-ies\)) /CreationDate (D:20151118135420+05'45') >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /SA true /SM 0.02 /ca 1.0 /CA 1.0 /AIS false /SMask /None>> endobj 4 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] endobj 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Contents 8 0 R /Resources 10 0 R /Annots 11 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595 842] >> endobj 10 0 obj << /ColorSpace << /PCSp 4 0 R /CSp /DeviceRGB /CSpg /DeviceGray >> /ExtGState << /GSa 3 0 R >> /Pattern << >> /Font << /F6 6 0 R /F7 7 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 11 0 obj [ ] endobj 8 0 obj << /Length 9 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream xÕOYrÄïý)úl`4,²Ù$ÃÀF2àÁðÁðÁõÚXx÷à¯ïÈî.Uvñ,;ÀÎ+_½?ù2###üÇßþýþ?ÿvÿãûßþçþ÷Ó¿ßÿv7Ü¯þùa¸_ïïwûíýïÜ}¾ÿ|÷ëÝ¯OÿýåßïVïvÛÕñ?_ÿò·þa=|ùÒósåo¿ÿõîÇã/Þ?ùíý??ý¯ÿ»_ßÿÓÓþrÿ¯ÿöô¯?~çø?î¶ý»Ãá°ßýà¿Ç¬Þ­a·Ú®OÿÇ*üùøÿºû¿»ÿë×A?®VÍÃÃf{ôøÏß;èÏ/_¾þ3þjò·¿üûÃîþé³ÿý»?a¯_ýùÌþt÷ãÇÇûÍãý§?ß¿ì/ÿúôÇÝÕ8ÜúÓýß?-ùð÷þr·þ2Ó'ë¯ ¯l¾~r8óÁÃñ;¯l¿~²ýàqúÁîøËÃë'ûãSFç0ý¡e}æ¹Êw~>þ³cóùÒû0U¿$¾õücxÍ¸*Ç¦"þR|ñøSáÁÃöÑpÚÁÚ3S<·q>|z:Ü=góq½Îa=¡ÙO¾éÙÌ÷xzþn½{wü£á&=ì eôù7÷Êîaÿnûõ&ùzLÿ8þVòr1½Î÷Ü1ßA¹jôpß8ÃñòX¯ÎÙ©øIÂVhÖ-Ìë6l§V(~ºòv©xÅÏßq±ó?ã0-25$O/ò¸Únvô³åý±`?¾g¨ß{×³ÇqøÖ Fàiï.Ô£KµîÀuÜßõg6ñh áöO ¿ó~zZãw×¿ó|2G¿´?ñÓáâe-ýtxÄ/Ñ »ðW>ÌÃá;ûðNa®ÂªÄÕ_Kg/l<Þ!á+qüq%o;¦£ ?ésÏâÍß1LÌKXÿ÷a8ñ¥âÄ©»f:oøãütxÞ°iOãùáñáùç>]û~6<¿²îãv;ãOaöyûd5hÿ8Q ×ÓYÛO83æ v.ýÃêì¼Æ1>LmDxÞ¾Ï ¯µ[§ÿ½Ú<ÿÜ05ZëéÂµñ&âh-}g7ýà¸à#ñð¶9-=#\!ÇÓ¹Å Nð¹  ãøHã8ù¿#Ó6L¿~6ÌizÇtéÂ¯Ä>#þðÐ°cÂ8Âò:sgÞîOø°´Ra×I  =üJxhøÙ°Ó}ùì¸lôþøå¤Â)~wUj82áð0Í<ôéF ç0qÊ·åSÖ²þºqù§s8v{¼ã¬ðÚ3óÓtìü³áí¦Ï`Û0Ìa§²nª8ôðaµÑü 7Wõ`Aø]²V¨Ù Zof7 n¥8SÓg:¼v8äaø8"½Õ§%-|c½qíf0Ð§P%àç<¸º_ôÆË -¦£~'C¸ÓÂ¾ sX¿f0¬CÝrÆ¾eâ@=N{8aË S¼l3nÝº?wHXÌ°1îGr·-z,GQ¹ùõ9G÷#~%ÌXp8è ËÀ±wX0|²KÃ{½BËýÆNð%^GpÙp(¡C°CÅK3sË6{hÙÝì/Ca¦Âé <³#_ûq5~ïõöîµ éH}Kù¸ÃÏ^ÉH0I}ÞS a°§Î`Ã¦w +<w<0=#°(o*üÄyoÇþ°!]oÂërÀQ_aÓu(ñ³Sw qû c«#Ø×_ÆVRøú$QKÖìÊÐÉfoðq3ûWkÁùV4Dçñ+xP,y !ELè`gÌçâÃ¯²WNßWÕU°ðAø ÁÄIÅ=®.ï¡°v[:Ë×ù%ì/?2ÇN` ðëò3ØáóÀ§.<#¸Zg&ìÁãtî¯Øv!ÁÃç!ø ìr`¸3-ubdxb,2½uã¼!ïr¨LHN|}¾|³Ï·öù TÂMä+]ýàì7>=r çâ½ÀN_=XfO§×+HXæ?µämä 5Ï0a`ÁmâÚ:Èã³,áÔ¯¸ø³* å ñfT(í%lÙx¤LæIõÁÕ·ÄÚOÜdÃÌ.$G&(|Ä8fd7áu Øá µøÎ>ÉqzµõKYA©:þ= 4ÊÄÙ)XrÓÿ®=­ØëðÄÐ Ü\à¬ÀLg_]pøêì° ×æò ÍvøÆXçLÀùUî²±HÕcÁDØÊ¶`h¾.#bJº#n è ÖÆ$üÞÿ<elÕy3;*Ð/ÔFÔ«ú\kÖ/;÷ú¼ØÌ^Îùfÿð¥àâ ·_Â@qÊNÀæ8:g$2 ½G¯^DêHXgJ,õ[J ¾»Ä[®Ûì'T´õåéáðÅ@NdàùípÊùeNã1öÎøÚH%Ñé4^H×8¬&ÿ ;\·â(da÷v½ÒAÆ,b_ Ù5z­tv°Â;;%w.S&×¢8!j·ÃhO õÌdT¯T'/Ëà qnQÿt Àm·[ 7B&ØÔ]âõTéMqQG ±¬® $t OaIÔ}Ä55ºZïX¬+g3¦9¹Ç®cRk dh*ËÜ<c3g½Ù }-±àâº2.Öj¡¥2©²ïI¥R½'5Bi¸!{<7!ë['ê ø¬B å<§ \9N¸¿î£¡.nw2'¸¥ú5äëæ *ðòÕÙ1ÍÅ0lAÉáX¼l(ÄoÑá#Âuæ+kØA3 Æº<váó^gä*.S&à¹KTÍ®÷óÈ"ë²r_¿:«À¼ ¢%ZâKßRà'x0uÃa^)U¶²·'Töð¶s¼ZýoTx,962¼tB®¬Nsã0Ð/" 5o½à0-$ÜÆ·£rZMUËù*IÐ ëØ ×w ÂÝæD¯!Æ°¶É+qB^UV¹^è'D@'Ú1G|92`ç,-DaÆp®#Ç¥P(Æ7Ñ;ÅÁCGôx]Ci¸Ò¢Cgo¾ !Á¯/ì¹Øÿ¿Loadn;ág5k¶mT{BëË!ú¿@v¹.MÍüH£Rû³¬%!¸K°7¯*ÆÁãfÓjàM%Z8ÔqqÁTÁjOláþ24 ¨N)`¦ìX íJÂºL^|¥ Å¥p{7l6;cB©·EáÑ¥DTÝ77ÃKa¤B&5<#° ³Ñzâ¶qÄ7wëõØ3XNV=àHë$LcòÜ2K°u$v6Lov÷f)ù½ ³ñ;*¸Âw5%Gõ]î×¨#¢ô IëßD¥ÙD(Ç¯þKsç8§X:& 3·@ HJV%«wtKÔ9*/rð/dD.õ¼¾LåPÝ^üRG¾4sæÌ5;|³ýÍB9¼¦2H¼Må¡ WwWeH9 Ý¨X`8±­RÎüz~=F¤ã&g,Õ5·c²Î4AS)ñv¥Fô,Â´oÂ÷2­*oÍIx{uf Å·¼W[_$ôÊVøb|È=`ÓÈÈ&MïLTa3°vCdÝ®fçòµuFÝHlêh)9jÇUd9[T¸¹ZÄã9*SùÆvÜ¼ÚBp¸¸°E¿¡¤#êNííØTd0/Áª ` C­iÇÞ ¨V ³E !ø2¼ØBwKõ õ*@\õ­Lµ45VâEf§;BÌú5 $/âuÔºîºD~4[ÿ×ës>¼$¨TPúÀX£½R<=[|?ô,O>ëyKÉXçá|ù¡ ¹ å*hô0ÞBßâ[à¼ <:V¹ñ¦p Â¡ZbáÍ¶(IXÈøÒC## Heading
```

Now I just want to create the pdf file with this content (get as report.content) and save on the server (In Report folder of the project).

Answer (score 0):

jsreport server returned you pdf document in string. simply you have to write this string into file. if you are using php you can do it by

> file_put_contents()

sample demo to represent what is returned from jsreport server

```
// Read the input pdf file in string
  $stringPdf  =  file_get_contents("input.pdf");

  echo $stringPdf;

// write string file in pdf
  file_put_contents("output.pdf",$stringPdf);
?>
```